# How to cause awk to fail if previous command (tar) also fails?

Tags: bash, awk, pipe

I have a bit of an issue with the following command which extracts a tar file & prints how many files have been extracted every second:

```
tar -xvf some_tar.tar -C a/directory | awk 'systime() > lasttime { lasttime = systime(); printf "%d files\n", NR; fflush(stdout) }'
```

Even if the tar command fails, the awk command will still return 0, which is undesirable because it does not reflect that the tar command failed.

How might I go about fixing this?

Answer (score 16):

If you just want to see if any command in the pipeline failed, set the `pipefail` option. It's supported in ksh, zsh and Busybox (at least), in addition to Bash. With that option set, the exit status of a pipeline is the leftmost non-zero exit status returned by the commands involved.

```
$ set -o pipefail
$ (exit 123) | true
$ echo $?
123
```

Or with the pipeline just in a conditional (this should say "it failed"):

```
set -o pipefail
if false | true; then
    echo it succeeded
else
    echo it failed
fi
```

Answer (score 8):

One approach in recent versions of `bash` would be to check the values in the `PIPESTATUS` array variable after you've invoked the `tar|awk` command pipeline.  Per the bash man page:

```
PIPESTATUS
   An array variable (see Arrays below) containing a list of exit status
   values from the processes  in  the  most-recently-executed foreground
   pipeline (which may contain only a single command).
```

So the exit code from tar would be in `${PIPESTATUS[0]}`, and the exit code from awk would be in `${PIPESTATUS[1]}`.

Comment: Or turn on `shopt/set -o pipefail` and then `$?` will be the status of the `tar` (given the `awk` had status zero)

Comment: To output whole array use `echo ${PIPESTATUS[*]}`

Answer (score 6):

Don't use a pipeline at all. Use a named pipe.

```
mkfifo p
awk '...' < p &
tar -xvf some_tar.tar -C a/directory > p
echo $?
```

The `awk` command runs in the background, blocking until `tar` starts writing to the named pipe. Once `tar` exits and closes its end of the pipe, `awk` will exit after reading what is left to read from its end. The `echo` command will report `tar`'s exit status, not `awk`'s.

Comment: Elegant solution!  Thank you.

Comment: This has to be the best answer, it really uses *Nix's power!

Comment: Actually, there's a bit of a problem I overlooked earlier. The point of running `awk` was to see its output; you can't do that when `awk` is running in the background. (Unless you run `tar` in the background as well, then put `awk` back in the foreground. But then you'll need to use `wait` to get the exit status of `tar` once `awk` exits, at which point this has ballooned way past the point where it's simpler than just using `PIPESTATUS`.)

Comment: Doesn't seem to be a problem, output from background processes shows up fine for me

Answer (score 5):

You don't really need to.  You can use the PIPESTATUS array to get the exit code from any of the programs in a pipeline.  You can also add up all the exit codes in the array to derive a status for the entire pipeline (if the sum is non-zero then something in the pipeline failed).

From `man bash`:

> `PIPESTATUS`
>
> An array variable (see Arrays below) containing a list of exit status
> values from the processes in the most-recently-executed foreground pipeline
> (which may contain only a single command).

Comment: Summing the array elements in the shell, hmm... `sum=$(tmp=("${PIPESTATUS[@]}"); IFS=+; eval echo "\$(( ${tmp[*]} ))")`...

Answer (score 3):

I expect calling `systime()` for every input line will slow down your pipeline significantly so the output from your pipeline won't accurately reflect how many files tar extracts per second. Consider only calling `systime()` once per thousand or million or something input lines or not calling `systime()` at all and just printing every thousand or million input lines if you want to see a progress indicator since you're not truly printing how may files have been extracted every second anyway.

Consider doing something like this to solve the problem you asked about and almost entirely remove the overhead of calling `systime()` (uses GNU awk for time functions and to have `$0` in `END` contain the last line read and to be able to have NUL in the input):

```
{ tar -xvf some_tar.tar -C a/directory && printf '\0\n'; } |
awk -v n=1000000 '
    BEGIN { beg = systime() }
    NR%n == 0 { printf "%d files processed\n", NR }
    END {
        end = systime()
        if ( $0 == "\0" ) {
            numFiles = NR - 1
            exitStatus = 0
        }
        else {
            numFiles = NR
            exitStatus = 1
        }
        printf "%d files per sec\n", numFiles / (end > beg ? end - beg : 1)
        exit exitStatus
    }
'
```

Comment: Have you measured this? It seems unlikely that systime would use any significant time compared to extracting and writing a file to the filesystem. On modern systems it would not even need a syscall, but even if it did, one clock_gettime syscall costs maybe at most 5% of all the open, write, fstat, chmod, close, etc. syscalls extracting a file would entail (and likely more like 1%).

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE - I hadn't when you asked but I just did a quick test and `time { seq 10000000 | awk '{print $0}' >/dev/null; }` output `real    0m1.916s
user    0m1.515s
sys     0m0.000s` while `time { seq 10000000 | awk '{print systime(), $0}' >/dev/null; }` output `real    0m6.212s
user    0m5.671s
sys     0m0.015s`. Feel free to try other things and post different timings if you like.

Comment: For me, the difference was about 2x with the systime and difference in volume of data written to /dev/null accounted fully for it. This was with GNU awk. Incidentally I also just discovered that busybox awk is flushing stdout after every print command, making it extremely slow for no apparent reason...

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE good point on the extra data being written.  When I changed it to `$ time { seq 10000000 | awk '{systime(); print $0}' >/dev/null; }` to remove the difference in volume of data written I got `real    0m2.734s
user    0m1.999s
sys     0m0.000s` so it took abut 1.5x the duration of the version without the systime() calls. I'm also using GNU awk,, version 5.2.1

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you add "**2>&1**" on the tar command, then, in the awk, move the print into the "**END{...}**" clause, with a conditional based on trapping the error message string.

**OR**, you could do something like

```
{ tar -xvf some_tar.tar -C a/directory ; echo "RC=$?" } | ...
```

and scan for that "**RC=**" condition and evaluate the result before doing the "**printf**".